# Evaluating a path in json from groovy - list elements are no longer returned as string

Tags: json, grails, groovy

I've got some tests for a API within a framework written in Grails, and as part of those tests I evaluate paths in JSON at run-time.

The JSON looks a bit like this (really hope I've got all the brackets right!):

```
{"someId":"big id here",
 "structure":
     [
         {"name": "item1", "questions":[
             {"name":"question1","answers":["I like cake"]}
             ]
         }
     ]
}
```

It's read in via:

```
JSON.parse(this.response.toString())
```

I evaluate the paths using

```
Eval.x(jsonVariable, 'x.' + pathVariable)
```

where pathVariable is the example path below. The problem occurs when I try to return/check a list.

An example path is

```
structure.find{it['name']=='item1'}.questions.find{it['name']=='question1'}.answers
```

A couple of days ago I was happily on Grails 2.2.4 and this worked fine. I got back

```
["I like cake"]
```

I've just upgraded to 2.3.2 and now I get

```
[I like cake]
```

I've checked the API directly but it's still returning valid JSON, so it's the parsing that's the issue. I'm very reluctant to rewrite my tests as there's lots of them and (more importantly) I would be rewriting them to check an incorrect value, which makes me uncomfortable.

Is there a work-around for this behaviour? Am I missing something?

Comment: to me the second version looks like a regular output `["I like cake"].toString()->[I like cake]`.  If you need the quotes there `["..."].inspect()` would give you the single quoted version. could you please also add, how you read your json there, what `pathVariable` is and/or how it relates to your example with the finds.  Why do you need the toString to be the exact form?

Comment: Apologies for the lack of clarity.

I read in the JSON response using the standard json parse method:
    **JSON.parse(this.response.toString())**

pathVariable is just the example path above.

I need the result from this exercise to be exact because the test appears to the user not as code but just as the example path above **and** the result. The users of the framework don't code, just test.

Comment: please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30256073/edit) the question.  comments are not good for code and important informations should go into the question.  can't you just Eval the user's expected input and compare it with the json-data?

Comment: Question edited. I do indeed eval the user's expected input and compare it - that's the problem. It used to return one thing, now returns another.

Comment: my guess then is, that you at some point flatten to a string.  if you have the user input evaled, you have a vector of string. reading from the json gives you a vector of string.  both can be compared for your test.